# Input validation in the keydown event

Tags: javascript, validation, dom-events, keydown

I'm attempting to do info validation against user text input in the process of `keydown` event. The reason that I am trying to validate in the `keydown` event is because I do not want to display the characters those that are considered to be illegal in the `input` box at the beginning.

The validation I am writing is like this,

```
function validateUserInput(){
   var code = this.event.keyCode;
    if ((code<48||code>57) // numerical
      &&code!==46 //delete
      &&code!==8  //back space
      &&code!==37 // <- arrow 
      &&code!==39) // -> arrow
   {
     this.event.preventDefault();        
    }
}
```

I can keep going like this, however I am seeing drawbacks on this implementation. Those are, for example:

1. Conditional statement become longer and longer when I put more conditions to be examined.
2. `keyCodes` can be different by browsers.
3. I have to not only check what is not legal but also have to check what are exceptional. In above examples, <kbd>delete</kbd>, <kbd>backspace</kbd>, and <kbd>arrow</kbd> keys are exceptional.

But the feature that I don't want to lose is having not to display the input in the `textarea` unless it passes the validation. (In case the user try to put illegal characters in the `textarea`, nothing should appear at all) That is why I am not doing validation upon `keyup` event.

So my question is:

1. Are there better ways to validate input in `keydown` event than checking `keyCode` by `keyCode`?
2. Are there other ways to capture the user inputs other than `keydown` event before browser displays it? And a way to put the validation on it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're checking a printable key, which is exactly what you seem to be doing, you should use the `keypress` event instead, since that's the only place you're going to be able to get reliable information about the character the keypress represents. You can't detect numeric keypresses reliably in the `keydown` event. Also, it's a bad idea to suppress arrow keys and delete/backspace keys. What do you gain from doing that?

There's also some errors: in Firefox, you'll need to get the `Event` object from the parameter passed into the event handler function, and if you're using a DOM0 event handler function rather than `addEventListener()` or `attachEvent()`, you should use `return false;` to suppress default behaviour. Here's my recommended code:

```
var input = document.getElementById("your_input_id");

input.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    if (/\d/.test(charStr)) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the preventDefault part. If you want to catch keys (by `event.keyCode`, or combinations using for example `event.ctrlKey` + `event.keyCode`), you check if the `keyCode` is allowed. If it is, simply return `true`, otherwise return `false`. If you return `false`, the key input will not be written to the input field, otherwise it will.

I can't think of better ways to then using keyCode. You can use `String.fromCharCode([keyCode])` if you want to check for specific character values, but it keeps boiling down to some loop to check the keyCodes you want to validate. May be a `switch ... case` could offer a bit more readability.

Here's a piece of code from a keydown event handler I use (just for demonstration, it doesn't actually do anything):

```
function handleKey(e, thisFld) {
        thisFld = (thisFld || this);
              e = e || event;
    if (!e) {
      return true;
    }

    var isCtrl = e.ctrlKey,
        isShift = e.shiftKey,
        isAlt = e.altKey,
        kc = e.keyCode || e.which,
        codes = [27, 38, 40],
        keys = {
                 escape: 27,
                 up: 38,
                 down: 40,
                 ins: 45,
                 del: 46,
                 one: 49
                };

    if (isCtrl && kc === keys.del) { ... }
    if (isAlt && kc === keys.ins) { ... }
        //etc
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. preventDefault wasn't necessary. Have applied String.fromCharCode too.

Answer (score 0):

here's a fiddle that you can play with and may provide more insight.

jsfiddle: [keydown/keypress demo w/ info display](http://jsfiddle.net/jaf0/LqJTu/)

It would appear that the latest browsers use preventDefault(). The code below is similar to what i put on jsfiddle but is standalone and can be pasted into an html file that you can access locally to test (note it's mobile friendly for device testing.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, width=device-width, user-scalable=no"/>
<style>
.b {color:blue;}
.r {color:red;}
input {font-size:18px;}
</style>
<script>
function byId(el) {return document.getElementById(el)}
function sfcc (n) {return String.fromCharCode(n);}
function foo(event) {
    var he='&#x'+event.keyIdentifier.split('+')[1]+';';
    var html=''
    var cn=event.target.className;
    html+='kc: [<span class="b">'+sfcc(event.keyCode)+'</span>] ';
    html+='wh: [<span class="b">'+sfcc(event.which)+'</span>] ';
    html+='he: [<span class="b">'+he+'</span>]<br>';
    for (i in event) 
        if (["string","boolean","number"].indexOf(typeof event[i]) >-1 && i.toUpperCase()!=i)
            html+='<span>'+i + '</span>: [<span class="r">'+event[i]+'</span>]<br>';
    byId('kc').innerHTML=html;
    switch (cn) {
        case "pd": event.preventDefault(); return;
        case "rf": return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
kp/pd: <input class="pd" type="text" onkeypress="foo(event)"/><br>
kp/rf: <input class="rf" type="text" onkeypress="foo(event)"/><br>
kd/pd: <input class="pd" type="text" onkeydown="foo(event)"/><br>
kd/rf: <input class="rf" type="text" onkeydown="foo(event)"/><br>
<div id="kc"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: incidentally using event.returnValue=false may work -- didn't check

Answer (score 0):

So, I've found that keypress is great for printable characters, and keydown for all the rest. You can check the `event.charCode` on `keypress` for printable characters (it should be 0 for non-printable).
You can use `event.keyCode` on `keydown` for arrows and such.

This is how I just got an autocomplete to work in Chrome and Firefox.