# javascript keyup and keydown events

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, keydown, keyup

I have a problem when I'm reading predecessor's JS code of a webapp project. I find that he used `keyup` event to get users input to validate, instead of `keydown` event. 
So, is there any problem with `keydown` event for this kind of job concerning browser compatibility. I found `keydown` works well in Firefox, Chrome and IE10.

Comment: have you seen any issues? or are you just asking if there will be any?

Comment: IE is always an expection :)

Comment: @scunliffe I'm asking if there will be any. Because I need keydown to trigger validation for user's input.

Answer (score 1):

If you are editing a textarea, on `keydown` the key hasn't put anything in the textarea yet. On `keyup`, the content of the textarea will be modified. I believe they have a different behaviour too if you press and hold a key.

Comment: Right. Today I found that if I use keydown I must use setTimeout to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the keypress event because keyup and keydown events correspond to keys being physically moved, whereas keypress corresponds to characters being entered into the field. Validation is based on characters in a field, keyup and keydown would be used for something like a game.

http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/KeyPress-KeyDown-KeyUp-The-Difference-Between-Javascript-Key-Events.aspx and 
[JavaScript: input validation in the keydown event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997805/javascript-input-validation-in-the-keydown-event)

Comment: keypress is OK. But it's not suitable here. Because the purpose of this piece of code is validating user's input. So there is some circumstance like this: My web don't allow user to input any letter in an input lablel. When you keep pressing a key, like "a", down using your left hand finger and not put up your finger, at the same time, click the submit button using your right hand. As a result, there will be many "a" in user's input. Because the validate function couldn't be invoked before the key is up. So it's easy to skip the validation via this method.

Comment: For this reason, I think keydown is a better choice.